# Bug appears when writing file from tkinter module

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Done!\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
        self.entrythingy = tk.Entry()
        self.entrythingy2 = tk.Entry()
        self.entrythingy.pack()
        self.entrythingy2.pack()
        # here is the application variable
        self.contents = tk.StringVar()
        self.contents2 = tk.StringVar()
        # set it to some value
        self.contents.set("stdio")
        self.contents2.set("script name")
        # tell the entry widget to watch this variable
        self.entrythingy["textvariable"] = self.contents
        self.entrythingy2["textvariable"] = self.contents2
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.text.pack()
        # and here we get a callback when the user hits return.
        # we will have the program print out the value of the
        # application variable when the user hits return
        self.entrythingy.bind('<Key-Return>',
                              self.print_contents)
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        #print("hi there, everyone!")
        self.fn = self.contents2.get()
        self.body = self.text.get(1.0, tk.END).split('\n')
        #print('Self.body:\n',self.body)
        self.libs = self.contents.get().split(' ')
        self.make_c()

    def make_c(self):
        lib_text = ''
        for i in self.libs:
            lib_text += "#include <lib.h>\n".replace('lib', i)
        body_text = "int main() {\n\t"+"\n\t".join(self.body)+"return 0\n}"
        print(lib_text+body_text)
        with open(self.fn+'.c', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(lib_text+body_text)
        print('File written!')
        from subprocess import call
        call(['gcc',self.fn+'.c', '-o', self.fn])


    def print_contents(self, event):
        print("hi. contents of entry is now ---->",
              self.contents.get())
        #self.contents.set("")

    #def 

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Those are the my code, which tries to make a c file and convert it. The problem is, when I convert it once, it is working fine, but when I change the content of the text box, the file doesn't change, and I don't understand why. I am sure that I put in the new file content, because it prints before it writes. Also, it appears that when I try to write files independent from tkinter, it works just the way I want it to.

I think there is some mechanism that I am not aware of in TK, or there is a bug. Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine for me. How are you confirming that the file doesn't change?

Comment: This is too much code. Please try to condense this down to a [mcve]. At best, all you need is an entry widget (and/or text widget), a button, and a tiny bit of code to tie it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It doesn't compile again due to the error in it when I added `return 0`, without semicolon. So, when I click the executable file, it shows the old program. I added the semicolon, and now it is fine. Thx everyone!